# Screen Receiver fired after 10 secs - Android Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have many broadcast receivers in my apps and when:

- I don't have any receiver called, my screen receiver is fired immediately.
- But, If there is another one (a notif receiver for example) called before, my screen receiver is fired 10 seconds after.
  How to avoid this behaviour and why it happens?

To give more details, these are my logs
The receiver (notif) starts a service (enqueuework) to start an activity.
But as you can check, the screen off intent is received 10seconds after the break from the notif receiver

````
2022-01-07 09:50:29.868 13352-13352/? I/: onCreate: lock screen finish
2022-01-07 09:50:29.868 13352-13352/? I/:  lockscreen onResume: 
2022-01-07 09:50:29.876 13352-13352/? I/:  lockscreen onResume: 
2022-01-07 09:50:39.238 13352-13352/? I/: onReceive: screen off intent receive```
````